# Mongoid and Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, active-model-serializers

I'm back to the drawing board with my json API, doing a few test to see if I can speed a few things up.

First thing I did, was to create a new rails application and configure it to be an `api_only` application

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "rails"
require "rails-api"

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
#require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)    
module testApi
        class Application < Rails::Application
            config.api_only = true
        end
end
```

Then I modified the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'rails-api'

#Database
gem 'mongoid'

#Response
gem 'active_model_serializers'
# gem 'active_model-shaz', github: 'kristianmandrup/active_model-shaz'
# gem 'mongoid-serializer'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Once I had these, I wrote an `ams initializer`:

```
Mongoid::Document.send(:include, ActiveModel::SerializerSupport)
Mongoid::Criteria.delegate(:active_model_serializer, :to => :to_a)


ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
  config.embed = :ids
  config.embed_in_root = false
end

module BSON
  class ObjectId
    alias :to_json :to_s
    alias :as_json :to_s
  end
end
```

and Wrote my models:

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, :type => String
  field :coordinates,  :type => Array
  field :lon, :type => Float
  field :lat, :type => Float

  has_many :posts

  #Relation Indexes
  index({ posts: 1 })

  #Class Indexes
  index({ name: 1 })
  index({ coordinates: "2d" }, { min: -200, max: 200 })
  index({ lon: 1 })
  index({ lat: 1 })
end


class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :place

  field :type, :type => String
  field :is_private, :type => Boolean, default: false
  #Relation Indexes
  index({ place: 1 })

  #Class Indexes
  index({ type: 1 })
  index({ is_private: 1 })
  index({ created_at: 1 })
  index({ updated_at: 1 })

end
```

Once I had these, I created my mongoid indexes and created a places_controller with a method to insert dummy data

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def dummy
    150.times do
      # create places
      @place = Place.new ({
                            :coordinates => [range(-117,-118), range(32,33)],
                            :name => "New place #{range(1,1000).to_i}"
                        })
      if @place.save
        150.times do
          @post = Post.new({
                              place: @place.id,
                              type: 'picture'
                          })
          @post.save
        end
      end
    end
    render :json => @place
  end

  def index
    @places = Place.all
    render json: @places
  end

  private
  def set_place
    @place = Place.find(params[:id])
  end
  def place_params
    params.permit(:name, :lon, :lat, :coordinates => [])
  end
  def range (min, max)
    rand * (max-min) + min
  end
end
```

I ran the dummy route multiple times giving me approx 800 places and a little over 100K posts to go along with it.

I then created a serializer using `rails g serializer place`, it didn't create it like I expected it to but eh i can wing it -- or so I think.  So I modified the serializer as I suspect it works.

class PlaceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :coordinates, :lat, :lon, :results
  has_many :posts

def results
    @results = "hello world"
  end
end

I then run the `/places` routes in the the terminal, and in postman and I get back all 800 places.  But, it's missing my key for results and my key for posts and I can't seem to figure out exactly why it's not working the way it should.

What I am getting back currently is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "55ae994c4a757304b4000000",
        "coordinates": [
            -117.80632651221987,
            32.35275002408346
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-07-21T19:11:08.162Z",
        "lat": null,
        "lon": null,
        "name": "New place 882",
        "updated_at": "2015-07-21T19:11:08.162Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "55ae994c4a757304b4000097",
        "coordinates": [
            -117.92741327810995,
            32.39414931372753
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-07-21T19:11:08.835Z",
        "lat": null,
        "lon": null,
        "name": "New place 284",
        "updated_at": "2015-07-21T19:11:08.835Z"
    }
]
```

The _id is coming back as a string, so I know that the initializer is working, as that's where I specify to turn `BSON` to a string in my return.